# Android Studio 1.4 - Explain activity_main.xml and content_main.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I just updated my Android Studio to 1.4, and I'm a bit confused about *activity_main.xml* and the other xml file *content_main.xml.*

I have this app that programatically generates xml. Everything is fine, except I don't have the action bar.

My onCreate is like this:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ...
   // set layout programatically


  setContentView(myCustomXML);
```

How do I get the action bar? There must be some very simple solution to this.

Comment: because in your code you are using Toolbar, and setting it as support actionbar

Comment: the code is what came with AndroidStudio, which is also why I was confused.

Comment: You mean the code, that is generated when you create new Blank Activity? If so please attach activity_main.xml, so that in future everybody may know what exactly your problem was

Answer (score 0):

Many [design components](http://android-developers.blogspot.sk/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) that were introduced with Android Lollipop version. The main problem you are probably not awared right now is the [`Toolbar Widget`](http://android-developers.blogspot.sk/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html#toolbar-widget).

As you can see in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, for `MainActivity` there is "...NoActionBar" theme used. Therefor there is no default actionbar placed on top od `activity_main` layout. Instead of that there is `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` component used and it is part of content XML.

Notice, that `Toolbar` is part of `activity_main.xml` and probably not part of your `MyCustomXML`.

If this is not your problem, then you probably just need to `setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)` or `setActionBar(android.widget.Toolbar)`.

After you have **set action bar** from your **layout.xml** you can get it via **`getSupportActionBar()` / `getActionBar()`** methods.

Hopefuly, this is what you are looking for, because your question is not 100% clear

**Edit:**
Do not use `setContentView()` twice and do not expect anything to work if you work with views before `setContentView()` method is called (Toolbar is also view)

Comment: Looking at the Android Studio tutorial I noticed they still refer to the previous version. Do you have any link to the official documentation regarding this issue? I could not find anything...